# Why does Virginia allow driving without vehicle liability insurance by paying an "Uninsured Motor Vehicle fee"?

Tags: united-states, regulation, public-safety, insurance, virginia

In the US state of Virginia, like in most countries/states in the world, [liability insurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liability_insurance) is mandatory for (drivers of) motor vehicles. However, unlike other countries, it is allowed to drive without liability insurance by paying an **Uninsured Motor Vehicle fee** of $500 per year:

> Uninsured Motor Vehicle Fee
>
> The Virginia Uninsured Motor Vehicle (UMV) fee allows a motor vehicle
>   owner to register an uninsured motor vehicle. At the time of
>   registration, the motor vehicle owner must certify whether the vehicle
>   is insured or uninsured.
>
> If the vehicle is uninsured, the motor vehicle owner is required to
>   pay to DMV a $500 uninsured motor vehicle fee in addition to normal
>   registration fees. Payment of the $500 fee does not provide the
>   motorist with any insurance coverage. [...]

*[Uninsured Motor Vehicle Fee, Virginia Department of Motor Vehicles](https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/vehicles/#uninsured_fee.asp)*

Note that the payment is not just a penalty for being uninsured - after paying it, you are actually allowed to drive without liability insurance (though you will have to pay any accident damages yourself).

---

This does not make sense to me. Why would one require liability insurance, but then allow people to opt out? The goal of mandatory insurance is that accident victims get their compensation - if you allow opt-outs chances are that drivers who opt out are mostly drivers with little money or high accident risk, so precisely those where having insurance is most important.

I can understand not requiring insurance at all (based on the idea that government should not interfere), but requiring insurance and allowing an opt-out seems pointless.

So what is the rationale / background for this policy? Did any lawmaker go on record explaining the motivation?

Comment: First thing to check is whether you're allowed to actually drive an uninsured car or you're just being allowed to register the car so you can keep your plates.

Comment: @pboss3010: You are allowed to drive if you pay, you just remain liable for any damage you cause. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Sounds great for drivers who's premiums would be > $500 and can either cover the liability or don't have any assets

Comment: Are you looking for theoretical reasons or statements by people who actually voted on the rule explaining their vote?

Comment: In case that an uninsured driver causes an accident and is unable to cover the damages, does the state of Virginia pay them (totally or partially). IOW, is the state acting as a last resouce insurer?

Comment: @SJuan76: I don't think so. The revenue from the fees goes to an [Uninsured Motorists Fund](https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/commercial/#insurance/umvfee.asp) which subsidizes the cost of the uninsured motorist insurance coverage (and is required in insurance plans), and through that coverage the damage involving uninsured drivers is covered. This just seems like a weird system.

Comment: Just guessing, but the state may not have the power to actually force anyone to get cover, but may have the power to tax the uninsured. Similar to the “Obamacare” individual mandate.

Comment: @chirlu considering most states have laws requiring your car to be insured to get registered and give tickets for driving without proof of insurance coverage I am not sure that is the case. Though in most cases it is a fix-it ticket meaning that you can show proof of insurance coverage afterwards to get out of the ticket.

Comment: Speculation: “Uh, well, no. Neddy doesn't believe in insurance. He considers it a form of gambling.”

Comment: This is the text of the law (although not certain it's the only relevant law): my reading is that the scheme only applies to people who have had their ability (or as they call it a "privilege") to drive suspended as a result of not having insurance. https://vacode.org/46.2-707.1/

Comment: @StuartF: As far as I can see, the law you link to is only about the _payment plan_ for the fee (for cases where the uninsured driver cannot / did not pay). The law about the fee itself is [§46.2-706](https://vacode.org/46.2-706/), and [§ 46.2-707](https://vacode.org/46.2-707/) sets penalties for not paying. There, no preconditions are mentioned, so it seems you are free to choose between getting insurance and paying $500 per year.

Comment: To my knowledge, if a driver without insurance is involved in the accident and cannot pay the damages, it is the state that is liable to pay them (or at least can be attacked in court), since it failed to enforce its own requirement for insurance. Asking uninsured  drivers to legalize themselves at low cost has the double benefit of being able to track them and having some money to repay the damages that they cause. This perhaps outweighs the risk of those who would use it as a way to opt out of insuring themselves (and risk paying high damages in a case of an accident.)

Comment: @RogerVadim: " if a driver without insurance is involved in the accident and cannot pay the damages, it is the state that is liable to pay them" - are you sure? I don't think the state is liable. As mentioned in my answer, there was a special fund for paying such claims, maintained by insurance companies.

Comment: @sleske This is how you do it in other states - you attack the state, because it allowed an uninsured driver on the road. Virginia clearly tries to preempt such situations. Whether the state pays directly or by giving money to insurance companies is a matter of practical implementation. Btw, which insurance company, if the driver is uninsured?

Comment: @RogerVadim: Ah, ok. I don't know which insurance company exactly - the article I read only said "special fund for insurance companies" so it maybe it is a fund that is managed by all companies together...

Comment: Aren't there some religious groups that consider insurance to be immoral? Or was that just Ned Flanders on the Simpsons.

Comment: @StuartF: Yes, it seems that at least some Islamic scholars consider insurance to be forbidden by Islamic law (similar to interest payments being forbidden). No idea whether this motivated the rule, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Answering my own question after four years...*

It seems I am not the only one who questioned this regulation.
In March 2023, [Senate bill SB 951 was signed into law](https://fastdemocracy.com/bill-search/va/2023/bills/VAB00024279/), which abolishes the "Uninsured Motor vehicle fee":

> SB 951
>
> Repeals the option to register an uninsured motor vehicle upon payment
> of the uninsured motor vehicle fee of $500. The repeal has an
> effective date of July 1, 2024. [...]

So, my question is now moot.

---

As to the original intent behind the rule, an article in Repairer Driven News sheds some light:

> Virginia is among two states (New Hampshire is the other) that don’t
> require vehicles to carry liability insurance as long as drivers pay a
> $500 uninsured motor fee.
>
> The surcharge does not provide drivers with any coverage. It goes into
> a special fund for insurance companies whose policyholders were
> injured or their vehicles damaged by an uninsured driver.

*[Senate bill would require auto liability insurance in Virginia](https://www.repairerdrivennews.com/2023/02/15/senate-bill-would-require-auto-liability-insurance-in-virginia/)*

As [this page from the VA DMV](https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/commercial/#insurance/umvfee.asp) explains, the fund was paid out to insurers who offered uninsured motorist insurance, in proportion to the premiums they took in, so it compensated them for their expenses and payouts, not the drivers. Drivers who made the payment were still liable for lawsuits so it didn't provide any insurance against being sued or coverage against expenses from legal action.

So the idea seemed to be that drivers could opt out of liability insurance, and the fee would then support insurance companies which offer uninsured motorist coverage, in the hope that most victims of such uninsured drivers have uninsured motorist coverage themselves.

Of course, if you did not purchase uninsured motorist coverage, you were out of luck. That makes the system inferior to just requiring liability insurance, and I suppose that was one reason why the system was abolished

Comment: "replacement for liability insurance that only protects the victims" - but isn't that the whole point of liability insurance ("3rd party insurance"): to protect the victims? If one has liability [only] insurance, one doesn't have "protection for themselves" by definition. If, under that defunct legislation, a special fund covers the victims, it then _acts like_ liability insurance. Except, perhaps, it doesn't prevent from claims for damages, but then $500/year sounds like a reasonable (or even high) premium for "proper" car liability insurance...

Comment: @Zeus: Liability insurance also protects the policy holder - it protects them from having to pay for the damages they caused. It's not clear how the fund in Virginia worked, but if it cannot cover the damage in full, the guilty driver was probably still on the hook - thus no "protection" for the driver / policy holder.

Comment: Maybe my answer was a bit unclear. Edited to clarify.

Comment: [This page from the VA DMV](https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/commercial/#insurance/umvfee.asp) says the fund was paid out to insurers who had to cover losses from accidents caused by uninsured drivers, so it compensated them for their expenses and payouts, not the drivers. [Drivers who made the payment were still liable for lawsuits](https://www.marksandharrison.com/blog/accident-uninsured-driver-virginia/) so it didn't provide any insurance against being sued or coverage against expenses from legal action. It allowed drivers to insure themselves while reimbursing insurance companies.

Comment: @StuartF: Thanks for finding the links. So that means there was no direct compensation to victims from the fund, it was a subsidy for insurance companies. And uninsured drivers would be fully liable for any damages they caused - thus the fee provided no protection to them like a liability insurance would.

Comment: Edited my answer with that information.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can understand this odd rule by looking at who wins and loses here. While risk-averse Virginian drivers would like everyone to carry insurance, the fee privileges others to avoid buying it. The constituency that benefits from paying this fee instead of buying (presumably more expensive) insurance has both an optimistic belief they won't get into accidents and a low income; those are the people the rule is written to benefit. Representatives that vote for such a law do so to support the interests of their constituents pinched the most by the cost of liability insurance. Another state with an uninsured motor vehicle fee is South Carolina.

Comment: "Representatives that vote for such a law do so to support the interests of their constituents pinched the most by the cost of liability insurance" - that does not quite make sense to me. If you want to allow people to drive without liability insurance, just drop the insurance requirement. But having a requirement and then allowing people to get around it seems pointless. Why keep the requirement at all?

Comment: I can only offer that law is made from realpolitik, not good sense.

Comment: In theory it allows the wealthy to insure themselves by paying for any losses out of their own money (the [minimum legal requirements](https://www.marksandharrison.com/blog/accident-uninsured-driver-virginia/) for third party insurance were formerly only $60,000 per accident for medical bills plus $20,000 for property damage, so a moderately wealthy person could cover that - although it might not be enough in practice). In practice, it allowed people who had no money and would otherwise face high insurance rates (because they were bad risks) to avoid getting insurance. Not good.